# how to set margin to the modal on selecting the options from select drop down inside the same modal

Tags: css, angular, typescript

how to adjust margin top to modal content when the option is selected inside the modal, when person selected margin top for modal should be 260px if company selected its should be 300px

### guide.html

```html
<div bsModal #addGuide="bs-modal" class="modal fade guide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Guide Type</label>
            <ng-select [options]="guide" [(ngModel)]="addGuide.value" name="Guide" class='filterDropDown' placeholder="Guide Type" notFoundMsg="No Category Found">
            </ng-select>
          </div> 
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="addGuide.value == 'person'">
            <md-input-container>
              <input type="text" mdInput name="Name" placeholder="Person Name" [(ngModel)]="addName">
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container>
              <input type="text" mdInput name="DOB" placeholder="Person DOB" [(ngModel)]="addDob">
            </md-input-container>
          </div> 
          <div class="form-group" *ngIf="addGuide.value == 'company'">
            <md-input-container>
              <input type="text" mdInput name="AddCompName" placeholder="Company Name" [(ngModel)]="addCompName">
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container>
              <input type="text" mdInput name="Add Company Description" placeholder="Company Description" [(ngModel)]="addCompDescription">
            </md-input-container>
          </div>           
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          Footer
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### guide.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './guide.html'
})
export class GuideComponent{
 constructor() {}
 guide:any = [{ label: 'person', value:'person'}, {label: 'company', value:'company'}];
}
```

### style.css

```css
.pin .modal-content {
  margin-top: 260px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using **ngStyle**

```
<div [style.margin-top.px] = "addGuide.value == 'person' ? '260' : '300'"></<div>
```

You can also add class conditional and add important css

> last of your css page

```
<div class="modal-content" [ngClass]="{'margin260': addGuide.value =='person','margin300': addGuide.value == 'company'}"> 
.pin .modal-content.margin260{
    margin-top: 260px !important;
}
.pin .modal-content.margin300{
    margin-top: 300px !important;
}
```

Comment: Initially it is set to 250px in style.css. So ng Style value is not taking after selecting person not taking the value. Thank You for trying

Answer (score 1):

```
<div bsModal
  [style.margin-top]="modalMarginTop"
  #addGuide="bs-modal"
  class="modal fade guide"
  tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
```

In your component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './guide.html'
})
export class GuideComponent{
    // note removal of type annotation that was degrading typescript checking
    guide = [{ label: 'person', value:'person'}, {label: 'company', value:'company'}];

    @ViewChild('addGuide') addGuide: {value: guide[keyof guide]['label']};

    get modalMarginTop() {
      switch (this.addGuide.value) {
        case 'person': return '260px';
        case 'company': return '300px';
      }
    }
}
```